# how can we merge sum and count?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sum

My result of the request of group by is :

```
ref       state       quantity     total
PO3253    assinged    300.0        323400 
PO3253    done        300.0        323400
```

When I delete state from group by using:

```
SELECT   ref, sum(quantity),sum(price*quantity)  as total
FROM     myTable
GROUP BY ref
```

I get:

```
ref       quantity     total
PO3253    600.0        646800
```

I want the result to be:

```
ref       quantity     total
PO3253    300.0        323400
```

I want to do something like this operation :

```
SELECT   ref, sum(quantity)/count(*),sum(price* sum(quantity) / count(*))
FROM     myTable
GROUP BY ref
```

Comment: `SUM` divided by `COUNT` is called `AVERAGE`

Comment: Show us the actual query and some sample data, not just the output. I fear there are some details missing, which are crucial to solving the issue. @Remus hinted on the problem, you may simply want `average(price*quantity)` but we can't be sure.

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ _AVG_ works for this example. I cannot post the details  it's a complicated request.

Comment: So you don't mind getting irrelevant answers? We don't mind complicated queries, on the contrary. Without details, I have voted for this to be closed.  Do you really don't care whether the answer is `AVG(price*quantity)` or `SUM(price*quantity)/SUM(quantity)` or `SUM(price*quantity)/SUM(price)` or ...? There are many possible scenarios for such queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   ref, AVG(quantity), AVG(price*quantity)
FROM     myTable
GROUP BY ref
```